# group by having a unique id

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm trying to do a `group by`. However, this unique id field prevents me to do it.

Can you please help me to resolve this issue.

thanks.

scenario 1

```
select box.name, box.description, box.id
from box
group by box.name, box.description, box.id
order by box.id
```

update:
I've already solved the first scenario 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/111e7/16/0

scenario 2

```
select box.name, box.description, box.id, sum(box.amount) as amount
from box
group by box.name, box.description, box.id
order by box.id
```

update:
I've already solved the second scenario 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/449b7/2

Comment: add some sample data & desired result would easy to help.

Comment: Please provide the table structure - otherwise the request doesn't make sense at all: grouping only by a unique ID is NOT possible.

Comment: Please add the query you're trying to make and the response you get. This question is impossible to answer without that

Comment: Then remove the unique id! what else ?

Comment: I need a unique id to do a order by

Comment: What you need is some kind of aggregate function such as COUNT(_columnname_), otherwise it doesn't know what to do with the grouping

Comment: Btw, what are your goals with using group by? The way you use it doesn't make a lot of sense. You should group by a subset of the columns, not all of them

Comment: Yeah, it is really unclear what you are hoping to achieve here. You need to explain why you need to group, and why you need to order.

Comment: I'm trying to remove the duplicates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Comment: If you only need to order the query results, remove the group by line: select box.name, box.description, box.id
from box order by box.id

Answer (score 1):

For remove duplicate

```
;WITH xx AS
(
    select 
        [rn] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ORDER BY Id),
        name, description, id
    from box    
) 
SELECT 
*
FROM xx
WHERE 
    [rn] = 1
```

Or

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
*
FROM xx
ORDER BY 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to keep either the MAX or MIN box id and use that to order by. This will remove duplicates and still leave you a value to order by.  For example (using MAX)

```
select box.name, box.description, MAX(box.id) box_id, sum(box.amount) as amount
from box
group by box.name, box.description, box.id
order by MAX(box.id)
```